# Exception in System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage()

Tags: c#, wpf, crash, nullreferenceexception, caliburn.micro

We're catching the following exception from the field in our .NET4 Windows application. The stack trace doesn't point us to a code location in our app and we don't know how to reproduce the problem. We know about it only because the app is reporting the crash to our servers.  We also found some similar stack trace issues related to Caliburn.Micro, and this issue started shortly after we integrated CM into our solution.

Any ideas on where we should look or how we can reproduce this?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.         
 at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
 at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
 at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
 at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullReferenceException in System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620304/nullreferenceexception-in-system-windows-interop-hwndkeyboardinputprovider-filte)

Comment: Do you have the code for this application?  If so you should run it from VS and see which line the Exception is being thrown.  That will help you track down the issue.

Comment: Per the description, we're unable to reproduce the issue and therefore do not know where it is thrown.  We only know about it from the exception handling code we have in the app that is catching this exception out in the field.